# Power BI - Conditional Formatting based on RLS

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

Is it possible based on RLS, create a conditional formatting in a certain value/measure?

For example, having the cost value/measure, and if I put the users in a role called Green, for example, these users will see the negative values ​​in green. If I put the users in a role called Red, these users will see negative values ​​in red.

Because right now I'm creating two reports just because of this feature, if there was any way to have everything in one report it would be great.

I tried searching but didn't find much information, if someone can help me in achieving this, I would appreciate it very much.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

It is not even necessary to use RLS in this case. It would be overkill and would require you to support it in production as well.

Best idea would be to load an unconnected table with all user emails and their "configuration" (make the table invisible inside the datamodel) to your datamodel.

[image]

Then, you can use [conditional formatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/create-reports/desktop-conditional-table-formatting) as suggested by david like this:

1. create a helper measure in your dataset, that retrieves the color of the user.

```
UserColor = 
VAR LoggedInEmail = USERPRINCIPALNAME()
RETURN
    CALCULATE(
        SELECTEDVALUE(user[color]),
        user[email] = LoggedInEmail
    )
```

2. use the measure as described in the link with conditional formatting option

PS: in certain situations (e.g. local power bi report server) you need to use USERNAME() function instead

Comment: RLS has the advantage that you can add/remove users to roles without changing the code.  But if you want to specify this in the dataset design itself, then sure no RLS is needed.

Comment: hey guys, with @DavidBrowne-Microsoft answer I created my solution. Basically I created a disconnected table with color names, for example Red and Green. And after I created this measure: Logic Color =  VAR v = [Cost Growth MoM] VAR d = MIN ( 'Color RLS'[Color])
RETURN
SWITCH(TRUE(),
d =  "Red" && v < 0, 0,
d =  "Green" && v < 0, 1,
2)

After I created the conditional formatting and roles Red and Green and put a test user in red role, I tested it and it works nice, so thanks a lot guys, it helped a lot !!

Answer (score 1):

Sure.

> If you have a field or measure with color name or hex value data, you can use conditional formatting to automatically apply those colors to a column's background or font color. You can also use custom logic to apply colors to the font or background.

[Conditional Formatting - Color by Color Values](https://If%20you%20have%20a%20field%20or%20measure%20with%20color%20name%20or%20hex%20value%20data,%20you%20can%20use%20conditional%20formatting%20to%20automatically%20apply%20those%20colors%20to%20a%20column%27s%20background%20or%20font%20color.%20You%20can%20also%20use%20custom%20logic%20to%20apply%20colors%20to%20the%20font%20or%20background.)

So have an unconnected table with the "color names or hex values", and then use RLS to control which users can see which color rows.